# Batch-file for-loop and use of delims

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have created a batch file in a windows server to parse the name of the files stored in a folder.
The name of the file contains a set of parameters splitted by the hyphen, e.g. 
ACC-INV-APR-2015

I need to check the syntax correctness of the first two parameters (department and document type) e.g. I would avoid that the hyphen is inserted more than a time in the file name.
On the basis of the check, the files with wrong syntax will be moved to a folder.

We have to consider that, apart the first two parameters that are mandatory, the other ones could be skipped and therefore the file name could have some repetitive hypens after the first two parameters, e.g.

FIN-DOC-APR-2015--MFH-P01

We would avoid to have some file name like: FIN--DOC-APR-2015-MFH-P01

I have created the following batch file but I don't know how to skip the filename with wrong syntax....

Thank you.

---

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set source=\\fileserver\share$\archive
set dest_ok=\\fileserver\share$\fileok
set dest_not=\\fileserver\share$\error

FOR /R %source% %%f in (*.*) do call :Proc1 "%%f"
goto End


:Proc1
Set filename=%1%
For %%A in (%filename%) do (
    Set Folder="%%~dpA"     
    Set Name=%%~nxA
)

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=- " %%a in ("%Name%") do call :Proc2 %%a %%b
goto :eof

:Proc2
set department=%1
set typedoc=%2
FINDSTR /x "%department%" c:\0_scripts\arch\departments.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 FINDSTR /x "%typedoc%" c:\0_scripts\arch\typedocs.txt
if %errorlevel%==0  move /Y %filename% %dest_ok%
if %errorlevel%==1  move /Y %filename% %dest_not%
goto :eof


:End
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for regular expressions.  The Windows utility `findstr` will let you match based on a regular expression.  It exits status 0 if found, non-zero otherwise.  This lends itself to [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution).  In a cmd console, enter `findstr /?` for details on supported regexp syntax.

It'll also speed things up to cache the contents of departments.txt and typedocs.txt into variables, rather than open, read, close, repeat for each file checked.

So, with that in mind, here's how I'd do it:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "source=\\fileserver\share$\archive"
set "dest_ok=\\fileserver\share$\fileok"
set "dest_not=\\fileserver\share$\error"
set "departments.txt=c:\0_scripts\arch\departments.txt"
set "typedocs.txt=c:\0_scripts\arch\typedocs.txt"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%departments.txt%") do set "dept=%%~I;!dept!"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%typedocs.txt%") do set "type=%%~I;!type!"
endlocal & set "dept=%dept%" & set "type=%type%"

for /r "%source%" %%I in (*) do (

    rem // Does filename match /^[a-z]+-[a-z]+/i ?
    echo %%~nxI | findstr /i "^[a-z][a-z]*-[a-z][a-z]*" >NUL && (

        rem // Yep.  Check whether department and doc type is in allowed list.
        for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=- " %%a in ("%%~nxI") do (

            // if %dept% doesn't equal itself with %%~a removed, and so on...
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            if not "%dept%"=="!dept:%%~a=!" if not "%type%"=="!type:%%~b=!" (

                // All checks passed.  Moved to OK folder.
                move /y "%%~fI" "%dest_ok%"
            )
            endlocal
        )
    )
    // If the file hasn't been moved by now, it must've failed a test.
    if exist "%%~fI" move /y "%%~fI" "%dest_not%"
)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help.
I tried but there is something that doesn't work .... because all the file name are always correct even if the file name has a separator inserted two times ( e.g. MFH--FAT ) or if the document type or the department 
name doesn't exist. 
I have also inverted the destination folder on the basis of the "if" result.

Comment: I have inserted a "pause" command before the "move" statements to see what is happening . I enclose you below what it is reported :

Comment: So why is `MFH3-FHW-20150529-F001MD14895-20301231-V01-OP20-TRIFLEX-CP1_H--.pdf` not correct?  It has only one `-` between department and type, the department exists in departments.txt, and the type exists in typedocs.txt.  Are you saying you don't want `--` *anywhere* in the file name?  This contradicts what you originally said in your question: *"the other ones could be skipped and therefore the file name could have some repetitive hypens after the first two parameters"*

Comment: The file MFH3-FHW-20150529-F001MD14895-20301231-V01-OP20-TRIFLEX-CP1_H--.pdf is correct.  I am not contradicting what I said before. It is important that "--" is not inserted in the first two parts of the file name. Maybe I have not chosen the right example... anyway what I am saying that all the files are considered correct even if there are "--" in the first two parts of the file name.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\0_scripts\arch>(
echo MFH3-FHW-20150529-F001MD14895-20301231-V01-OP20-TRIFLEX-CP1_H--.pdf   | findstr /i "^[a-z][a-z]*-[a-z][a-z]*"   1>N
UL  && (for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=- " %a in ("MFH3-FHW-20150529-F001MD14895-20301231-V01-OP20-TRIFLEX-CP1_H--.pdf") do (

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 if not "TEF6;TEF10;QMM8;QMM73;QMM72;QMM71;QMM7;QMM6;QMM13;QMM1;QMM;MFP2;MFP1;MFH3;MFH2;MFH1;MFH ;MFG3;MFG22;MFG21;MFG2;
MFG11;MFG1;MFG;MFB;HSE;COS;" == "!dept:%~a=!" if not "WPL;WP;WBP;WB;WAL;WAG;WA;VTL;VTK;VDP;VBT;VBL;VB;VAW;VAP;VA;UVA;UMV
;TSS;TRN;TKU;TDC;SYM;SWD;SWC;SW;SVS;SVA;SV;STR;STL;STF;STB;SPC;SBT;SAM;RTZ;RTP;RPL;RP;RNO;RHW;RAW;QMP;QMA;QM;QBG;QB;QAM;
PZB;PUM;PRV;PRS;PRJ;PRA;PQP;PPM;PPK;PP;PNR;PLB;PH;PFH;PDV;PDR;PDC;PDB;PAP;PAL;PAG;OPS;OPL;OEE;NOR;NKA;MUB;MSZ;MON;MOD;MB
B;MNT;LZT;LZS;LZN;LPV;LPN;LPL;LPC;LPA;LHT;LDP;LBA;KSB;KPV;KPA;KOE;KOB;KBU;KBL;KB;IAM;HZG;HZ;HSE;HRB;HFG;HF;HE;HAZ;GMD;GE
Z;GBB;FVT;FRM;FPL;FPK;FPI;FPA;FP;FMP;FME;FMD;FMA;FLP;FLB;FIM;FHW;FGY;FGV;FGS;FGP;FGL;FGK;FGE;FGD;FGB;FGA;FDA;FA;EZZ;EWZ;
EWS;EVT;EV;ETZ;ETL;ESZ;EPB;EP;ECM;DVL;ECR;DV;DRX;DRW;DRV;DRQ;DRK;DRF;DMD;DIF;DLP;DER;DDI;DBL;DB;DAT;D01;CPC;CIP;CHL;CE;C
AP;BVT;BVS;BVB;BV;BUG;BSV;BST;BSS;BS;BPZ;BLD;BDL;BBL;BBD;BB;BAL;BAD;ANH;AGZ;AFK;AEN;AED;AAW;AA;" == "!type:%~b=!" (
move /y "\\server1\digit$\deposito\MFH3\MFH3-FHW-20150529-F001MD14895-20301231-V01-OP20-TRIFLEX-CP1_H--.pdf" "\\server1\digit$\errori"
 pause
)
 endlocal
) )
 if exist "\\server1\digit$\deposito\MFH3\MFH3-FHW-20150529-F001MD14895-20301231-V01-OP20-TRIFLEX-CP1_H--.pdf" move
 /y "\\server1\digit$\deposito\MFH3\MFH3-FHW-20150529-F001MD14895-20301231-V01-OP20-TRIFLEX-CP1_H--.pdf" "\\server11\digit$\ok"
 pause
)
        1 file(s) moved.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Blockquote

I have changed the script and came back to your original version .

This is the output of the batch file when a file correct is processed:

if exist "\server1\digit$\deposito\MFH3\MFH3--FHW-20150512-F01MD14861-20301231-V02-OP20-TRIFLEX-CP1H--.pdf" move
/y "\server1\digit$\deposito\MFH3\MFH3--FHW-20150512-F01MD14861-20301231-V02-OP20-TRIFLEX-CP1H--.pdf" "\server1\
digit$\errori"
 pause
)
        1 file(s) moved.
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\0_scripts\arch>(
echo MFH3-AFK-20150511-F01MD12340-20301231-V07-OP20-TRIFLEX-CP1_H--.pdf   | findstr /i "^[a-z][a-z]*-[a-z][a-z]*"   1>NU
L  && (for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=- " %a in ("MFH3-AFK-20150511-F01MD12340-20301231-V07-OP20-TRIFLEX-CP1_H--.pdf") do (
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 if not "TEF6;TEF10;QMM8;QMM73;QMM72;QMM71;QMM7;QMM6;QMM13;QMM1;QMM;MFP2;MFP1;MFH3;MFH2;MFH1;MFH ;MFG3;MFG22;MFG21;MFG2;
MFG11;MFG1;MFG;MFB;HSE;COS;" == "!dept:%~a=!" if not "WPL;WP;WBP;WB;WAL;WAG;WA;VTL;VTK;VDP;VBT;VBL;VB;VAW;VAP;VA;UVA;UMV
;TSS;TRN;TKU;TDC;SYM;SWD;SWC;SW;SVS;SVA;SV;STR;STL;STF;STB;SPC;SBT;SAM;RTZ;RTP;RPL;RP;RNO;RHW;RAW;QMP;QMA;QM;QBG;QB;QAM;
PZB;PUM;PRV;PRS;PRJ;PRA;PQP;PPM;PPK;PP;PNR;PLB;PH;PFH;PDV;PDR;PDC;PDB;PAP;PAL;PAG;OPS;OPL;OEE;NOR;NKA;MUB;MSZ;MON;MOD;MB
B;MNT;LZT;LZS;LZN;LPV;LPN;LPL;LPC;LPA;LHT;LDP;LBA;KSB;KPV;KPA;KOE;KOB;KBU;KBL;KB;IAM;HZG;HZ;HSE;HRB;HFG;HF;HE;HAZ;GMD;GE
Z;GBB;FVT;FRM;FPL;FPK;FPI;FPA;FP;FMP;FME;FMD;FMA;FLP;FLB;FIM;FHW;FGY;FGV;FGS;FGP;FGL;FGK;FGE;FGD;FGB;FGA;FDA;FA;EZZ;EWZ;
EWS;EVT;EV;ETZ;ETL;ESZ;EPB;EP;ECM;DVL;ECR;DV;DRX;DRW;DRV;DRQ;DRK;DRF;DMD;DIF;DLP;DER;DDI;DBL;DB;DAT;D01;CPC;CIP;CHL;CE;C
AP;BVT;BVS;BVB;BV;BUG;BSV;BST;BSS;BS;BPZ;BLD;BDL;BBL;BBD;BB;BAL;BAD;ANH;AGZ;AFK;AEN;AED;AAW;AA;" == "!type:%~b=!" (
move /y "\server1\digit$\deposito\MFH3\MFH3-AFK-20150511-F01MD12340-20301231-V07-OP20-TRIFLEX-CP1_H--.pdf" "\bars
rv11\digit$\ok"
 pause
)
 endlocal
) )
 if exist "\server1\digit$\deposito\MFH3\MFH3-AFK-20150511-F01MD12340-20301231-V07-OP20-TRIFLEX-CP1_H--.pdf" move
/y "\server1\digit$\deposito\MFH3\MFH3-AFK-20150511-F01MD12340-20301231-V07-OP20-TRIFLEX-CP1_H--.pdf" "\server1\
digit$\errori"
 pause
)
        1 file(s) moved.
Press any key to continue . . .